# Cant post photo to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Im using facebook sdk version 4.0.1 and HelloFacebook sample, I couldnt post photo in my app so i tried using the HelloFacebook sample as is only with the following changes :

1. in res/values/strings.xml - changed app id to mine
2. in AndroidManifest changed com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider suffix to my app id.
3. changed package using android tools to my app's package

now that i open the app the login succeded and canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos is true, yet when i post a photo FacebookCallback shareCallback.onSuccess is called, with result.getPostId()==null, and later HelloFacebookBroadcastReceiver.onFailedAppCall is invoked with this extras param : `Bundle[{com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_ACTION=com.facebook.platform.action.request.FEED_DIALOG, com.facebook.platform.status.ERROR_TYPE=UnknownError, com.facebook.platform.protocol.CALL_ID=cf2a7a61-7d74-4b0f-acbd-e48326c70f46}]`

my app doesnt have publish_action premissions, though it is documented that ShareDialog doesnt require that, so i dont get it... what could be the problem?

Comment: In res/values/strings.xml, did you also change app_name to your app's name as on the Facebook dashboard?

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: @HermannKlecker no, it just disappeared after some time from itself...

Comment: Interesting. So as if facebook takes time to process the app registration process or so? How much time are we talking about?

Comment: All right. Thanks a lot. Yes it disappeard whthin an hour or so.